# How to restrict the height of <tr> if there is a text area inside <td>

Tags: html, css

I have a html table with following structure

```
<table>
<tr class="border_bottom">
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><textarea></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thje height of text area is flexible. My problem is the wrapper tr/td height should not be increased as per the text area.

I want tr/td height constant and text area height should be overflow the td

Unfortunately I dont have the liberty to change html. I am looking for a solution purely based on css.

Code:https://jsfiddle.net/5u1mk39t/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this closer to what you're after?
*Edited for jQuery wrap function.*

```js
$("textarea").wrap("<div class='with-textarea'></div>");
```

```css
tr.border_bottom td {
  border: 1pt solid black;
}
tr.border_bottom td textarea {
  width: 200px;
}
.with-textarea {
  height: 55px;
}
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="border_bottom">
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Hello Karl.. Thanks for the answer. This is the exact behavior I wanted.. but I am working on a product and I dont have the liberty to introduce a div inside the td. Can this behavior achieved without changing html (only with css)?

Comment: I don't think so, all I can suggest here is that you target the textarea with JavaScript and wrap it with the `div`...

Comment: You probably know this, but using jQuery, you'd need something like `$( "textarea" ).wrap( "<div class='with-textarea'></div>");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <style>
tr.border_bottom td {
  border:1pt solid black;
}
tr.border_bottom td textarea{
 width:200px; 
 max-height: 55px; 
}
</style>
<table>
<tr class="border_bottom">
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><textarea></textarea></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This would just set a max-height.. to the text area.. i dont want the height of text area to be restricted, rather want to restrict the height of td and text area can grow beyond it

Answer (score -1):

Try and put a

```
max-height: xx px;
```

on the text area style / class